# Error "assignment from incompatible pointer type" when creating a Netfilter kernel module

Tags: c, linux-kernel, netfilter

I'm implementing a "mini firewall" and use the filter function with the signature shown below:

```
unsigned int minifw_inbound_filter(unsigned int hooknum, struct sk_buff *skb, const struct net_device *in,
                                const struct net_device *out, int (*okfn)(struct sk_buff *));
```

When I added the netfilter kernel module:

```
static struct           nf_hook_ops nfho_in;

nt init_rule_match_module(void) {
nfho_in.hook        = minifw_inbound_filter;        // filter for inbound packets
nfho_in.hooknum     = NF_INET_LOCAL_IN;             // netfilter hook for local machine bounded ipv4 packets
nfho_in.pf          = PF_INET;
nfho_in.priority    = NF_IP_PRI_FIRST;              // we set its priority higher than other hooks
nf_register_hook(&nfho_in);
```

I tried to compile my module and got a compilation error:

```
error: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
     nfho_in.hook  = minifw_inbound_filter;  // filter for inbound packets
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that's the correct function signature? Your compiler seems to think it isn't.

Comment: Possibly relevant: [What is the correct way to define a Netfilter hook function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25124033/253056)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hook function's type declaration changes depending on what kernel you're compiling against. That pattern looks to be from the [2.6 kernel](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v2.6.39.4/source/include/linux/netfilter.h#L103).

The current function signature looks like:

```
unsigned int nf_hookfn(void *priv, struct sk_buff *skb, const struct nf_hook_state *state);
```

It's likely you're referencing old sample code for this - you should try to find a newer example more aligned with the kernel you are compiling against.

However, as Paul R mentions in the comments to the question, if you want to harden the code so that it can compile against multiple releases of the linux kernel, you can use the [solution suggested in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44186227/17833), which wraps it based on the kernel/RHEL environment you're building against.

The problem is that the netfilter hook function signature changed at least three times since 2.6 - in the 3.13 kernel timeframe, in the 4.1 kernel timeframe and again in the 4.4 kernel timeframe, all changing the signature.